# <had been vs were > when... had been

Tags: tense, past-perfect

Background：She was held back when a bunch of people beat her father to death.

> After the crowd dispersed, she remained like a stone statue,her body and limbs in the positions they **were** in when the two old janitors had held her back.

From *The Three-body Problem,*  A novel translated from Chinese.

Is the verb tense （bold part） correct?  Shouldn't it be **had been**？

Comment: "were" sounds right to me, but I just know what I know from being a native speaker. My lack of formal education means that I cannot explain why I think it is correct.

Comment: @Harold Thanks,  That is sufficient to dispel my doubts.  I just want to know how native speakers feel about this sentence.

Comment: Had been sounds more awkward, though it makes sense.

Comment: _Had been_ sounds fine to me, but perhaps it would be better followed by _the janitors held her back_. Two past perfects in one sentence is a bit much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **were** here more appropriately conveys the meaning as there was no change in the positions of the body and limbs - the positions were (and remained) the same.  Using **had been** suggests that the body and limbs were *no longer* in those same positions, which is contrary to the statement that they remained in those positions.

To most readers either form would be considered equivalent and as a British English speaker both sound correct.